# Can Summarise in dplyr not drop other columns in my data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with three columns in it and I am attempting a simple summary to find the maximum temperature for each city in the data frame, but also keep the date listed for each max temperature.

Here is the data frame:

we'll call it maxT

```
  new.ID       Date   Max_TemperatureF
1     TUS 1960-04-05               87
2     TUS 1984-04-24               86
3     TUS 1972-04-01               75
4     TUS 2006-04-14               91
5     TUS 2000-05-03               96
6     PHX 1960-04-05               93
7     PHX 1984-04-24               93
8     PHX 1972-04-01               84
9     PHX 2006-04-14               91
10    PHX 2000-05-03               99
11    LAS 1960-04-05               91
12    LAS 1984-04-24               86
13    LAS 1972-04-01               81
14    LAS 2006-04-14               81
15    LAS 2000-05-03               98
16    LAX 1960-04-05               72
17    LAX 1984-04-24               69
18    LAX 1972-04-01               73
19    LAX 2006-04-14               63
20    LAX 2000-05-03               69
21    SAC 1960-04-05               82
22    SAC 1984-04-24               75
23    SAC 1972-04-01               64
24    SAC 2006-04-14               71
25    SAC 2000-05-03               81
26    PSP 1960-04-05               98
27    PSP 1984-04-24               91
28    PSP 1972-04-01               91
29    PSP 2006-04-14               81
30    PSP 2000-05-03               9
```

Each city has 5 temperatures listed and I would like to find the maximum for each city and then also list the date. I am using dplyr and have tried a quite a few variations of this code, but Date is always dropped in the final product. Is there a way to add a condition like drop=FALSE or something similar?

```
maxT <- tbl_df(maxT) %>%
  select(new.ID,Date,Max_TemperatureF)%>%
  group_by(new.ID) %>% 
  summarise(max_temp= max(Max_TemperatureF))
```

This is the output I keep getting:

```
 new.ID max_temp
1    LAS       98
2    LAX       73
3    PHX       99
4    PSP       99
5    SAC       82
6    TUS       96
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could try either `filter` or `slice`.  If there are ties for the maximum 'Max_TemperatureF' and want to get all those rows,

```
 tbl_df(test) %>%
      group_by(new.ID) %>% 
      filter(Max_TemperatureF==max(Max_TemperatureF))
```

Or we can get the index of the rows with `which.max` and subset with `slice`

```
 tbl_df(test) %>% 
       group_by(new.ID) %>% 
       slice(which.max(Max_TemperatureF))
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. I attempted filter, but I had the syntax wrong. Thank you very much. Also, thanks for adding slice in there, I'll explore that more and look for future uses.

Answer (score 4):

**Base package**

```
merge(aggregate(Max_TemperatureF ~ new.ID, df, max), df, all.x = T)
```

Output:

```
  new.ID Max_TemperatureF       Date
1    LAS               98 2000-05-03
2    LAX               73 1972-04-01
3    PHX               99 2000-05-03
4    PSP               98 1960-04-05
5    SAC               82 1960-04-05
6    TUS               96 2000-05-03
```

**sqldf package**

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT [new.ID], Date, max(Max_TemperatureF)
      FROM df
      GROUP BY [new.ID]")
```

Output:

```
new.ID       Date max(Max_TemperatureF)
1    LAS 2000-05-03                    98
2    LAX 1972-04-01                    73
3    PHX 2000-05-03                    99
4    PSP 1960-04-05                    98
5    SAC 1960-04-05                    82
6    TUS 2000-05-03                    96
```