# data mining: subset based on maximum criteria of several observations

Tags: r, subset

Consider the example data

```
Zip_Code <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4)
Political_pref <- c('A','A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','B','A','A')
income <- c(60,120,100,90,80,60,100,90,200,200,90,110)
df1 <- data.frame(Zip_Code, Political_pref, income)
```

I want to `group_by` each `$Zip_code` and obtain the maximum `$income` based on each `$Political_pref` factor.

The desired output is a df which has 8obs of 3 variables. That contains, 2 obs for each `$Zip_code` (an A and B for each) which had the greatest income

I am playing with `dplyr`, but happy for a solution using any package (possibly with `data.table`)

```
library(dplyr) 
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Zip_Code) %>% 
  filter(....)
```

Comment: You can group by zip_code and political pref and summarise it with the  max function? `df %>% group_by(zip_code, political_pref) %>% summarise(m = max(income))`

Comment: `aggregate(income~Zip_Code+Political_pref, df1, max)` ?

Comment: also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657753/can-summarise-in-dplyr-not-drop-other-columns-in-my-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice` with `which.max`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Zip_Code, Political_pref) %>%
   slice(which.max(income))
```